# av_dump_format gets correct fps, trying to copy its source doesn't

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I'm trying to use the FFmpeg libraries to process video files, and I need to get the video's fps. I'm loading mp4 h264 videos with constant fps.

My code is a slightly modified copy of the [demuxing and decoding example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/demuxing_decoding.c). I removed the code for outputting video and audio, as well as all the audio related stuff altogether. The `open_codec_context` function is unchanged besides removing the audio stuff.

After calling `open_codec_context`, my code does the following:

```c
if(open_codec_context(&video_stream_idx, &video_dec_ctx, fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) >= 0)
{
    video_stream = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx];

    double fps = get_fps(video_stream);
    
    printf("Framerate: %f\n", fps);
}

av_dump_format(fmt_ctx, 0, src_filename, 0);
```

`av_dump_format` prints the video stream's fps as: `25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc`

I checked the [source for `av_dump_format`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6af21de373c979bc2087717acb61e834768ebe4b/libavformat/dump.c#L621), and for each stream it calls [`dump_stream_format`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6af21de373c979bc2087717acb61e834768ebe4b/libavformat/dump.c#L505), which, along other things, does the following:

```c
static void dump_stream_format(const AVFormatContext *ic, int i, int index, int is_output)
{
    // (...)
    const AVStream *st = ic->streams[i];
    // (...)
    
    // The part where it actually prints the fps
    if(st->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        int fps = st->avg_frame_rate.den && st->avg_frame_rate.num;
        int tbr = st->r_frame_rate.den && st->r_frame_rate.num;
        int tbn = st->time_base.den && st->time_base.num;

        if (fps || tbr || tbn)
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "%s", separator);

        if (fps)
            print_fps(av_q2d(st->avg_frame_rate), tbr || tbn ? "fps, " : "fps");
        if (tbr)
            print_fps(av_q2d(st->r_frame_rate), tbn ? "tbr, " : "tbr");
        if (tbn)
            print_fps(1 / av_q2d(st->time_base), "tbn");
    }

    // (...)
}
```

So I copied the logic into a `get_fps` function:

```c
static double get_fps(AVStream *st)
{
    int fps = st->avg_frame_rate.den && st->avg_frame_rate.num;
    int tbr = st->r_frame_rate.den && st->r_frame_rate.num;
    int tbn = st->time_base.den && st->time_base.num;

    if(fps) return av_q2d(st->avg_frame_rate);
    if(tbr) return av_q2d(st->r_frame_rate);
    if(tbn) return 1.0 / av_q2d(st->time_base);
}
```

But the result it returns is nonsense.
I made my code just print the values for `avg_frame_rate`, `r_frame_rate` and `time_base` and got:

`avg_frame_rate` has random values each time I run it (including negative), seems like initialized garbage.

`r_frame_rate` is 0/0.

`time_base` also has random values like `avg_frame_rate`.

---

Does anyone know what's going on? How does `av_dump_format` get the correct fps?

I tried different video files with the same result.

Comment: Not all video containers stores the the `avg_frame_rate` information. In case your input is an MP4 file, the code supposed to work. For MKV file, there is no `avg_frame_rate` information. What is the container of your input?

Comment: Why do you use _logical_ OR as in (e.g.) `int fps = den || num;`??? Do you want: `int fps = den ? den : num;`?

Comment: I checked the source code. In the source code there is `&&` not `||`: `int fps = st->avg_frame_rate.den && st->avg_frame_rate.num;`

Comment: This trick relies on "short circuit evaluation" of `&&`. It is customarily used inside an `if` statement. I've _not_ seen it used in the way you're using it. And, it probably still won't work. That's because `den && num` is a _logical expression_: it _must_ return _only_ 0 or 1 regardless of the values of the individual terms. You really _do_ want: `int fps = den ? den : num;`

Comment: My bad, my code uses `&&`, I made a mistake when copying it. I'll edit the question to correct it. The `&&` is shorthand for `den != 0 && num != 0` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've figured out where the problem was.

I had built ffmpeg from source (master), and I must've messed up the config because something was missing. The linker very helpfully found the missing library in my regular ffmpeg from my package manager (stable 4.4.1). So my program was linking against half master and half 4.4.1, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Turns out the random values I was getting came from that undefined behaviour. Linking with the stable 4.4.1 build directly fixed the issue and now I `get_fps` returns the expected values.

I'm surprised I got this far without noticing. Not even a segfault.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).